# How to create auto add ShortUUIDField in Django

Tags: django

I need to create a django ShortUUIDField that automatically generate the value when the entry is created:

Here's my code:

```
def generate_short_uuid():
    string_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    return string_uuid.replace('-', '')[:12]


class ShortUUIDField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['default'] = generate_short_uuid
        kwargs['editable'] = False
        kwargs['unique'] = True
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['max_length'] = 12

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        if add:
            while True:
                try:
                    value = generate_short_uuid()
                    setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
                    return value
                except IntegrityError as e:
                    if 'duplicate key' in str(e):
                        continue
                    raise
```

Here's the model that use the field:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    uuid = ShortUUIDField()
    user = models.OneToOneField("users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
```

Here's the error that occurs when I try to create the entry:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "uuid" of relation "profiles_userprofile" violates not-null constraint

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ShortUUIDField from the shortuuidfield library to create a field that automatically generates a short universally unique identifier (UUID) for each instance of a model.

First, you'll need to install the shortuuidfield library using pip:

**pip install django-shortuuidfield**

```
from django.db import models
from shortuuidfield import ShortUUIDField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: nice but now is it secure to use this id to make GET requests? I mean the problem I was trying to solve with UUID it was not to expose the internal database ID, and now is it not the same?

Comment: yes, it is secure from the default id. u can make a GET request. and it's up to you whether you will expose or not. but it is secure then default id